# Gulp 4: How to use gulp.series() and gulp.parallel() inside a function?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want to define a Gulp 4 task that is a composition of three functions executed in series.  However, I want to define it as a named function rather than using `gulp.task()`:

```js
function beforeTest() { ... }
function coreTest() { ... }
function afterTest() { ... }

export function test() {
    // what goes here?
    // this function should be equivalent to:
    // gulp.task('test', gulp.series(beforeTest, coreTest, afterTest));
}
```

I found a similar [question](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1093) asked on the Gulp GitHub issue tracker where the OP tried the equivalent of the following:

```js
export function test() {
    return gulp.series(beforeTest, coreTest, afterTest);
}
```

The reason why this does not work is explained in the GitHub issue.  The recommended solution from the Gulp team was to not use a named function but to rather assign the composite function to a variable:

```js
export const test = gulp.series(beforeTest, coreTest, afterTest);
```

However, this solution appears deficient for a few reasons.

The first deficiency was raised in a [comment](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1093#issuecomment-111651322) on the GitHub issue about the restriction this places on task ordering (something I was already trying to avoid by using named functions instead of `gulp.task()` due to the new [requirement](https://gulp.readme.io/docs/gulpseriestasks) in Gulp 4 that task names must be registered before they are referenced).

The second deficiency is more cosmetic (and thus triggers my OCD :-) ).  When running `gulp test`, the composite `test` task is displayed in the output:

```
[00:00:00] Starting 'test'...
[00:00:00] Starting 'beforeTest'...
[00:00:00] Finished 'beforeTest' after 106 ms
[00:00:00] Starting 'coreTest'...
[00:00:00] Finished 'coreTest' after 214 ms
[00:00:00] Starting 'afterTest'...
[00:00:00] Finished 'afterTest' after 280 μs
[00:00:00] Finished 'test' after 324 ms
```

However, if I have another composite task that references `test`, such as:

```js
gulp.task('build', gulp.parallel(lint, test));
```

Then when I run `gulp build`, the composite `test` task is not displayed in the output:

```
[00:00:00] Starting 'build'...
[00:00:00] Starting 'lint'...
[00:00:00] Starting 'beforeTest'...
[00:00:01] Finished 'beforeTest' after 1.08 s
[00:00:01] Starting 'coreTest'...
[00:00:02] Finished 'coreTest' after 977 ms
[00:00:02] Starting 'afterTest'...
[00:00:02] Finished 'afterTest' after 232 μs
[00:00:07] Finished 'lint' after 6.96 s
[00:00:07] Finished 'build' after 6.96 s
```

I suspect this may be because Gulp does not display any function whose name is `series` or `parallel`.  I tried setting `test.displayName`, as suggested in the GitHub issue:

```js
export const test = gulp.series(beforeTest, coreTest, afterTest);
test.displayName = 'test';
```

But that didn't change the output of `gulp build`.  I also tried setting `test.name`, but that property appears to be frozen:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function 'function series(done) {
    nowAndLater.mapSeries(args, asyncDone, extensions, done);
  }'
```

It seems that if I could define the composite `test` task as a named function, it would address both of these deficiencies.  So, in summary, how would I define the body of the `test` function shown at the top of this question?

Answer (score 3):

```js
export function test(...args) {
    return gulp.series(beforeTest, coreTest, afterTest)(...args);
}
```

The function arguments must be passed through to the composite function returned by `gulp.series()` in the event any component function requires the Gulp task callback parameter (i.e. `cb`, `done`, whatever).

This task definition produces the desired output when running `gulp build`:

```
[00:00:00] Starting 'build'...
[00:00:00] Starting 'lint'...
[00:00:00] Starting 'test'...
[00:00:00] Starting 'beforeTest'...
[00:00:01] Finished 'beforeTest' after 1.06 s
[00:00:01] Starting 'coreTest'...
[00:00:02] Finished 'coreTest' after 949 ms
[00:00:02] Starting 'afterTest'...
[00:00:02] Finished 'afterTest' after 302 μs
[00:00:02] Finished 'test' after 2.05 s
[00:00:07] Finished 'lint' after 7.12 s
[00:00:07] Finished 'build' after 7.12 s
```

**EDIT:** A deficiency of this solution is that by deferring the call to `gulp.series()` until the `test` task is actually executed, the child tasks do not show up in the task map displayed by `gulp --tasks`.

For example, using the proposed solution, the output of `gulp --tasks` is

```
[00:00:00] Tasks for ~/gulpfile.babel.js
[00:00:00] └── test
```

Whereas, defining `test` as a variable as suggested in the original GitHub issue, the output is

```
[00:00:00] Tasks for ~/gulpfile.babel.js
[00:00:00] └─┬ test
[00:00:00]   └─┬ <series>
[00:00:00]     ├── beforeTest
[00:00:00]     ├── coreTest
[00:00:00]     └── afterTest
```

This isn't an issue for the question posed because the `beforeTest`, `coreTest`, and `afterTest` functions are not actual tasks (i.e. they are not `export`ed), so I actually do not want them to show up.  But, because I can easily see getting into the same situation with `export`ed subtasks, I don't feel this solution is completely intellectually satisfying.